# How to reveal caption on hover while other divs remain in place

Tags: css, html, hover

When I hover over the image, the image next to it also moves downwards.

Is there any way to make sure that this doesn't happen and that the image next to it remains in its position - only the images underneath it move down?

I've made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/YJ96L/

HTML:

```
   <div id="kidz"><img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg"><span>yo</span></div>
 <div id="kidz"><img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg"><span>yo</span></div>
 <div id="kidz"><img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg"><span>yo</span></div>
 <div id="kidz"><img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg"><span>yo</span></div>
  <div id="kidz"><img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg"><span>yo</span></div>
 <div id="kidz"><img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg"><span>yo</span></div>
 <div id="kidz"><img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg"><span>yo</span></div>
 <div id="kidz"><img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg"><span>yo</span></div>
```

CSS:

```
  #kidz {
    width:300px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
            -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; -o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out; transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#kidz:nth-of-type(odd) {
    margin-right:10px;
}

#kidz:nth-of-type(even) {
 margin-left:10px;   
}

#kidz img {
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
}

#kidz span {
    display: block;
    background:#dcdcdc;
    color: #222222;
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
    font-size:10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: justify;
        -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    transition:all 0.4s ease;
}

#kidz:hover span {
        height: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ID only once in the page so it would be better to change from ID to class; so you can repeat classes many times. to fix the issue you have to define the `position:absolute` to `#kidz span` which I've change to `.kidz span`.

In addition its hover effect work for all images have to add `position:relative;` to ID `#kidz`. which I have converted in class `.kidz`. Check the ***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/YJ96L/4/)***.

```
.kidz {position:relative;}

.kidz span {
    display: block;
    background:#dcdcdc;
    color: #222222;
    position: absolute; /* Add position:absolute*/
    top:5px;
    font-size:10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    transition:all 0.4s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should turn your `#kidz` into `.kidz` . **ID can only be used once in document**.

Then , basicly , set parent container as `relative` and `span` to `absolute` .http://jsfiddle.net/YJ96L/1/

```
.kidz {
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.kidz:nth-of-type(odd) {
    margin-right:10px;
}
.kidz:nth-of-type(even) {
    margin-left:10px;
}
.kidz img {
    height:250px;
    width:300px;
}
.kidz span {
    display: block;
    background:#dcdcdc;
    color: #222222;
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    font-size:10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.4s ease;
    transition:all 0.4s ease;
}
.kidz:hover span {
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```
<div class="kidz">
    <img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg" /><span>yo</span>
</div>
<div class="kidz">
    <img src="http://www.1000fraggers.com/fraggersbrand/frag1000.jpg" /><span>yo</span>
</div><!-- and so on with as many .kidz + span needed :) -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following css property to your `#kidz` css:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

It should fix your issue.